# Filter Lat and Long from a list using a rectangle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, coordinates

What I have here is a program that pulls some info from a json object and displays it on a page. In this case Public Bike Stations. The json object provides a list of each stations latitude and longitude, so finding the points is not an issue.

What I am doing is trying to filter the list to only show stations that are within a rectangle of a user inputted lat and long coords.

I have no idea how I should filter out the lat and long from the json list that exceeds my rectangle

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#createlist").click(function() {
            var upperleftlatitude = Number($("#upperleftlatitude").val());
            var upperleftlongitude = Number($("#upperleftlongitude").val());    
            var lowerrightlatitude = Number($("#lowerrightlatitude").val());    
            var lowerrightongitude = Number($("#lowerrightongitude").val());
```

And this is where I am confused. I figured I would just write an if statement that said if the json lists lat and long was within the area of the rectangle based on the coords given by the user to  display only these stations but I have no idea how to write it

```
                  if ( ){
                    var table_row = "<tr class='stationrow'>"
                    table_row += "<td>" + station.stationName + "</td>";
                    table_row += "<td class='numeric'>" + station.availableDocks + "</td>";
                    table_row += "<td class='numeric'>" + station.availableBikes + "</td>";
                    table_row += "<td class='numeric'>" + station.latitude + "</td>";
                    table_row += "<td class='numeric'>" + station.longitude + "</td>";
                    table_row += "</tr>";
                    $("#stationtable").append(table_row);
                }   
            total_bikes_available += station.availableBikes;
            });
        $("#totalbikesavailable").html(total_bikes_available);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: And... do you have a question? Is your `if` statement not working? Is the output not formatted to your liking?

Comment: The question is I have no idea how to write the if statement to filter out the lat and long coords exceeding the rectangle. I know what I want it to do but I am confused as to how to write it

Comment: look up mbr http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the coordinates you want to check are `station.latitude` and `station.longitude`, and the four sides are named as you indicated in your code, then the condition becomes

```
if(station.latitude < lowerrightlatitude && station.latitude > upperleftlatitude && station.longitude < upperleftlongitude && station.longitude > lowerrightlongitude)
```

This is assuming that the names of your variables are sensible indications of where they are in the rectangle. You might want to convince yourself that this still works when the sign changes (use -ve values for West longitude, and South latitude, and you should be OK).

Comment: yeah sorry the lats and longs Im checking against are from the json list so it would be station.latitude and station.longitude